# Why Azure subnet does not shown in All resources?

Tags: azure, subnet

When I try to list down and export all resources from Home - All Resources, for some reason I couldnt find Subnet in them. I suspect it is due to the fact subnet is a child resource?

Comment: Before asking next question please read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

Subnet is not a resource, its a configuration of a Virtual Network.